# How to converting BMP to AVI C#

Tags: c#, image

I want to print screen 24 times in  1 second and then convert to AVI or VMW. İT's like video capture. is that possible ?

Comment: BMP is an image type of file, well, I didnt get you, how you want to convert image to video!

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Expression Encoder SDK which allows you to do (live) video capturing from the screen in C#/.Net.